# Why is the php version of Laradock different from the php version executed by the actual Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

Why is the php version in the laravel project not the same as the php version in the docker-compose workspace?

My laradock .env has set PHP_VERSION=8.1 and build.
Looks useful in workspace.

[image]

But when executing "echo phpversion()" in the actual Laravel project, the php version is 7.2.34? Please tell me how to make the Laravel project execute php 8.1.
Thanks a lot!!!!

[image]

(/laradock/nginx/sites/another.conf)
[image]

Comment: go to the workspace of your Laradock and execute the same things. Show the .conf file of your 'another.test' site

Comment: @UnderDog .conf file has been added.

Comment: `docker-compose exec workspace bash`, it will get you inside the workspace container. Now do your `php -v` and let's see that version. You might want to do something similar for the `php-fpm` container

Comment: I found that the php version in the workspace is 8.1, but the php version in php-fpm is 7.2.
Is it because my development computer macos 10.13 version is too low and the php-fpm compilation fails?

Comment: 2 answers, a short and a long one. 1) we now have https://laravel-news.com/laravel-herd specifically for Mac. 2) `docker-compose up --build php-fpm`, without the `-d` flag you will see the errors. Whenever you do PHP tasks, don't do it in your Mac, but do it in one of the containers. The workspace container is your "go-to" container, it has yarn, npm, composer and the right php. `php-fpm` should be running without errors. `docker ps` is your friend

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76776201/8963798
I opened a new question, please help me take a look.

Comment: Laravel Herd only supports versions above macos12... (My system is macos10.13)